# Sorting data from file in order from StreamReader

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, streamreader

I have a windows form that uses a StreamReader to read form data into some text boxes.  That works perfectly fine.  The problem now is that I want to display the data from the file in order alphabetically by names.  Early I tried an array.Sort method, by it didn't work so well.

Here is my code:

Note: I close the reader and file in the dispose method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ViewArchives
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const char DELIM = ',';
        const string FILENAME = @"F:\lscSpring2016\CIS2620\FinalProject\TicketMaster\bin\Debug\SoldTickets.txt";
        string recordIn;
        string[] fields;
        static FileStream file = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
                fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
                nameBox.Text = fields[0];
                ticketsBox.Text = fields[1];
                purchaseBox.Text = fields[2];
                dateBox.Text = fields[3];
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                label5.Text = "You have viewed\nall the records filed.";
                btnView.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM).OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray();`

Comment: Flow control via exception is not such great design. You should check the return value from ReadLine(); if null, you've reached end of file.

Comment: Why didn't Array.Sort() work?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way.

First, introduce a class for containing data from a single line:

```
class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tickets { get; set; }
    public string Purchase { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

In your `Form1` class do the followings:

Create two fields.
One for the record list and one for indicating the current index in the record collection.

```
Record[] soldTickets; // This will contain the file data
int currentRecordIndex = -1;
```

Create a method that loads the whole file in one step into the record collection:

```
private void LoadRecords()
{
    soldTickets =
        File
            .ReadAllLines(FILENAME)
            .Select(line =>
            {
                string[] data = line.Split(DELIM);

                return
                    new Record()
                    {
                        Name = data[0],
                        Tickets = data[1],
                        Purchase = data[2],
                        Date = data[3]
                    };
            })
            .OrderBy(record => record.Name)
            .ToArray();

    currentRecordIndex = -1;
}
```

Then your button click event handler can look like this:

```
private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Record currentRecord = soldTickets.ElementAtOrDefault(++currentRecordIndex);
    if (currentRecord == null)
    {
        label5.Text = "You have viewed\nall the records filed.";
        btnView.Enabled = false;
        return;
    }

    nameBox.Text = currentRecord.Name;
    ticketsBox.Text = currentRecord.Tickets;
    purchaseBox.Text = currentRecord.Purchase;
    dateBox.Text = currentRecord.Date;
}
```